# Why component data object properties are not rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js

properties in my component data object don't get used in the frontend. I´m new to Vue, so I hope to learn something new.

Following this quick-layout implementation, I installed the component and everything was fine: https://vuejsexamples.com/a-vue-plugin-to-quickly-generate-a-webapplication-layout/

I did set the variable `hiddenRight` to true, but in the frontend, it doesn't work:

```
data () {
    return {
        minifiedLeft: false,
        minifiedRight: false,
        hiddenLeft: false,
        hiddenRight: true,
    };
},
```

In my vue inspector all properties in `data` object are set to false. It seems they dont get updated.

[image: all variables are set to false]

Browser Cache is diabled:

[image]

The site gets reloaded every time is save the project. 
Can you give me a quick tip?

Thanks in advance!

Full Code: main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
   render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <vue-ads-layout :full-bar="true">

    <!-- Header -->
    <vue-ads-bar
      slot="toolbar"
      :fixed="true"
      class="bg-red">
      <!-- <vue-ads-menu-button slot="first" :hidden="hiddenLeft" @toggle="hideLeft"></vue-ads-menu-button> -->
      <vue-ads-menu-button slot="last" :hidden="hiddenRight" @toggle="hideRight"></vue-ads-menu-button>
    </vue-ads-bar>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <vue-ads-bar
      slot="footer"
      :fixed="false"
      :footer="true"
      class="bg-purple">
    </vue-ads-bar>

    <!-- OffCanvas -->
    <vue-ads-drawer
      slot="right-drawer"
      :minified="minifiedRight"
      :hidden="hiddenRight"
      :fixed="false"
      @minify="minifyRight"
      @hide="hideRight"
      class="bg-blue">
      <vue-ads-minify-button slot="bottom" :right="true" :minified="minifiedRight" @toggle="minifyRight"></vue-ads-minify-button>
    </vue-ads-drawer>

    <h1> Content! </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum laudantium modi aspernatur quibusdam, accusamus officiis eius labore quasi praesentium vero esse veritatis et pariatur sint magnam? Cupiditate est iusto cumque!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum laudantium modi aspernatur quibusdam, accusamus officiis eius labore quasi praesentium vero esse veritatis et pariatur sint magnam? Cupiditate est iusto cumque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, sunt ullam sint libero minus error perferendis quod fuga? Eius facere sint possimus maxime quaerat quae iusto. Optio rerum minima iure! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus doloremque mollitia, officiis non quidem quam labore aut ducimus vel libero architecto nihil repellendus, consectetur ipsam magni sed pariatur repellat tempore! lorem</p>

  </vue-ads-layout>

  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
  import '../node_modules/vue-ads-layout/dist/vue-ads-layout.css';
  import { VueAdsLayout, VueAdsBar, VueAdsDrawer, VueAdsMenuButton, VueAdsMinifyButton } from 'vue-ads-layout';

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        VueAdsMinifyButton,
        VueAdsMenuButton,
        VueAdsDrawer,
        VueAdsBar,
        VueAdsLayout
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        minifiedLeft: false,
        minifiedRight: false,
        hiddenLeft: false,
        hiddenRight: true,
      };
    },
    methods: {
        minifyLeft (minified) {
            this.minifiedLeft = minified;
        },

        hideLeft (hidden) {
            this.hiddenLeft = hidden;
        },

        minifyRight (minified) {
            this.minifiedRight = minified;
        },

        hideRight (hidden) {
            this.hiddenRight = hidden;
        },
    }, 
  }
</script>


<style lang="scss">

  @import 'reset.scss';
  @import 'variables.scss';
  @import 'layout.scss';

</style>
```

This is the module installed in node-modules:

[image]

Comment: Looks like chrome cache. Try to disable it. In console settings choose “disable cache while developer tools open”

Comment: thanks, but this setting is already checked

Comment: how/where is it getting set to true? which component's data is this, the app's, or some child component's?

Comment: Can you share the rest of your component?

Comment: @DanOswalt i did set the value of 'hiddenRight' to true manually in the data object, to hide the right Drawer by default.

Comment: @dvnguyen i added the full code to the question

Comment: Try using actual values like 'true' and 'false' in the 'methods' object.

Comment: @ZeekHuge well, if i do that, the function loses its purpose... e.g. change the hideRight method returning value to true, the drawer dissapears, but i can not toggle it any more

Comment: By the why, how can i check the components which get used in the main component? I Installed them via npm into node modules. There is a folder named "vue-ads-layout". So far so good. But inside im missing the child components e.g. "vue-ads-drawer". How could that be? I added a screenshot above.

Comment: I guess then you should check for the value of `hidden` and do opposite of that. Thus, you'll probably be able to toggle itm